# Android Studio how to swipe through pages?

Tags: android

Lets keep it really simple. Say I created 4 layout's called page_one, page_two, page_three, page_four. How can you make it so you can swipe through all those pages back and forth horizontally?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Use `ViewPager` to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a View Pager to achieve this. 
you can swipe through the pages by using a view pager.

you can go through this link

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Edit: 
  1) Create 4 layouts for 4 fragments view.

2) Create a activity which extends FragmentActivity.

3) Create an adapter for view pager and set the adapter in your main method.

4) You can use tabs also for this.

Comment: Please add some content to your answer. Link only answers are frowned upon

Comment: Ian yeah I updated my answer! with more explanation? can you tell me why you down voted my answer? Is it in-appropriate? he just asked how so I just give the method!

Comment: praneeth - The downvote didn't come from me so I can't be certain. It's probably for the same reason that I commented on - but I prefer to give someone a chance to fix the answer first.